# Setting custom transparency value to floatingActionButton in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[800],
      ),
```

How can I set custom opacity/transparency value to the floatingActionButton? Is there a property where the % of transparency be defined?

Answer (score 6):

you can set transparency of a floating button by adding opacity to its color

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.5),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the original color itself but to change the transparency only, use

```
Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer.withOpacity(0.5)
```

for the backgroundColor.